# How to transfer favorites tree items from one db to another in HeidiSQL?

Tags: transfer, heidisql, favorites

I'm trying to transfer favorites tree items from one database to a new one. Sometimes I have to import a database from my production environment into my local environment, and I have to name it differently (e.g. DB-0028) to keep my local database (DB-0024). Then I want to have marked favorites tree items in the new database which are the same as in the previous database.

[favorites tree items in local database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ejfk.png)

I tried to edit HeidiSQL settings file, but with no luck. Maybe you know better way to do that? Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- create an empty database in your local server
- select the wanted tables in the "Database" tab (not in the tree)
- rightclick, then click "Export database as SQL"

[image]

Then, in the upcoming dialog:

- in the "Output" dropdown, select your local server
- in the "Database" dropdown, select the empty database you created in the first step

Comment: Thanks for the response! Maybe I didn't describe the problem sufficiently. 
The "problem" is that I have tables with data in my DB-local and DB-prod datatables.
My goal is to transfer favorite markers (yellow stars) only :)

Comment: Yes I understood. But there is nothing you can do with the favorites, except for activating the "_Show only favorite tree items_" button. So you need to re-select these tables in the database tab.